# How to copy/text in html and paste in new file?

Tags: notepad++, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext, adobe-brackets

Is there any way by which we can search specific pattern from project(.html files) and paste it into new file.

Using sublime text.

And then from the list search and comment those keyword that are not present in one more file.

Example
HTML files

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="getAlt('imageAlt')">IMG</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="getAlt('imageAlt2')">IMG2</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="getAlt('imageAlt3')">IMG3</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" title="getAlt('imageAlt4')">IMG4</a>
```

Get the keyword'getAlt' key in new file

```
imageAlt
imageAlt2
imageAlt3
imageAlt4
```

Prop file

```
imageAlt ="www.abc.com"
imageAlt2 = "www.abc1.com"
imageAlt22 = "www.abc11.com"
imageAlt3 = "www.abc2.com"
imageAlt4 = "www.abc3.com"
```

Search in the prop file for same name and rest should be commented

result

```
imageAlt ="www.abc.com"
imageAlt2 = "www.abc1.com"
#imageAlt22 = "www.abc11.com"
imageAlt3 = "www.abc2.com"
imageAlt4 = "www.abc3.com"
```

Any way to do it in sublime or any other task editor.

Comment: you could write a python script to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Text editor CudaText has multi-carets. Use multi-carets to do selection. After word jump right. Then copy/paste block of text.

[Help text.](http://wiki.freepascal.org/CudaText#Multi-carets)